# Название района Киева

Tags: топонимика

Есть такой район Киева — Оболонь. А что означает это название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Википедии приводятся такие сведения о происхождении слова Оболонь: Оболонь — историческая местность на севере Киева, расположенная на правом берегу Днепра. Название происходит от старославянского слова *болонь* (есть в словаре у Фасмера), что означает 'заливной луг, затопляемая местность' (у Фасмера - 'поемный луг, низина').